# Creating Custom Role in Azure AD using Azure CLI instead of PowerShell

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am working with Azure Cloud Shell and need to create a custom role in "Entra ID" using Azure CLI, as demonstrated in the documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-create ]. The provided examples in the documentation are in PowerShell, but I prefer to use Azure CLI for this task.

I have already reviewed the documentation, but it primarily focuses on PowerShell commands. I am wondering if there is an equivalent process using Azure CLI commands.

Here is a snippet of the PowerShell example from the documentation:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-create]

Can someone guide me on how to achieve the same result using Azure CLI? Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is no direct CLI command to create custom directory roles in Microsoft Entra ID. Alternatively, you can call Microsoft Graph API using `curl` or `az rest` by generating token with Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, there is **no** direct Azure CLI command to create custom directory role in Microsoft Entra ID.  Alternatively, you can make use of either `curl` or `az rest` by calling Microsoft Graph API.

In my case, I used below **bash script** that calls `curl` request and got **response** like this:

```bash
TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com --query accessToken -o tsv)

REQUEST_BODY='{
   "description": "Can manage basic aspects of application registrations.",
   "displayName": "Application Support Administrator",
   "isEnabled": true,
   "templateId": "'$(uuidgen)'",
   "rolePermissions": [
       {
           "allowedResourceActions": [
               "microsoft.directory/applications/basic/update",
               "microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update"
           ]
       }
   ]
}'

response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$REQUEST_BODY" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions")

if [[ $response == *"error"* ]]; then
    echo "Error occurred: $response"
else
    echo "Custom admin role created successfully."
    echo "Response:"
    echo "$response" | jq .
fi
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, custom directory role named **Application Support Administrator** created successfully:

[image]

Comment: thanks , i wanted to ask if this role that created Graph API can be use for : role assignment of server principle of app registration, with cli command or i need to use the Graph API again for the role assignment

Comment: There is no direct CLI command for assigning roles too. You need to make use of Graph API again for role assignment.